# Como calcular a média excluindo os zeros no R?

Tags: r, matemática

Calculei a média dos seguintes valores:

```
MÉDIA = mean(c(12,20,15,0,7,0))

print(MÉDIA)

[1] "9"
```

Mas eu preciso da média que não considere os zeros:

```
MÉDIA_Sem Zeros = mean(c(12,20,15,7))

print(MÉDIA_Sem Zeros)

[1] "13,5"
```

Como posso calcular a média com a condição excluindo as variáveis de valor zero?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

É só indexar o vetor de modo a excluir os zeros.

```
x <- c(12,20,15,0,7,0)
mean(x[x != 0])
#[1] 13.5
```

Se o vetor tiver valores `NA`, use o argumento `na.rm = TRUE` ou a função `which`.

```
y <- x
y[3] <- NA

mean(y[y != 0], na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] 13

mean(y[which(y != 0)])
#[1] 13
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta vou testar.

Answer (score 2):

Outra solução é utilizar a função `subset`:

```
x <- c(12,20,15,0,7,0)

mean(subset(x, x != 0))
[1] 13.5
```

ou

```
mean(subset(x, x > 0))
[1] 13.5
```

No entanto, é preferível dar preferência ao operador `[`, como propôs o @Rui. Nesta [pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860090/why-is-better-than-subset) há uma explicação mais detalhada sobre a preferência do uso de `[` ao invés de `subset`.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta vou testar.